# IntelliJ file watcher uses wrong grunt

Tags: intellij-idea, gruntjs, project-setup

I'm setting up grunt with the IntelliJ file watcher plugin.
As you can see in the image I choose as path for my installed grunt the following: 
C:\Users\Max\AppData\Roaming\npm\grunt.cmd

Nevertheless if I save my project IntelliJ doesn't find my grunt...
If I execute grunt in the terminal with "grunt" all works.

[image: File watcher settings]

Comment: Do you get any error/warning message about missing grunt? Have you tried to run IDE as Administrator?

Comment: @y.bedrov yeah i got he following message: 
cmd.exe /D /C call C:\Users\Max\AppData\Roaming\npm\grunt.cmd
grunt-cli: The grunt command line interface (v1.3.2)

Fatal error: Unable to find local grunt.

If you're seeing this message, grunt hasn't been installed locally to
your project. For more information about installing and configuring grunt,
please see the Getting Started guide:

https://gruntjs.com/getting-started

Process finished with exit code 99